# How can I add Image into List of Item?

Tags: android

```
 ArrayList <ClipData.Item> dataList = new ArrayList<ClipData.Item>();
```

How can I add Image data in dataLIst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Clarify, Why would you want to do such a thing and what is the source of the data? Network Download or Just a local asset/image or resources for initialization process of the application?
A good scenario would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In drawable right click an select New>Image assert(or vector assert if you want to add icon) and select your image . Choese a name and next and finish.

**easy way:**

Copy your images from your file manager and simply right click and paste it in drawable folder.

You can rename it with refactor > rename